# Yet another many-to-many NHibernate question

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, database

Trying to implement relatively simple relationship between `User` and `Role`. `User` can be in many roles, same `Role` can belong to any number of `User`s. `Role`s are shared, i.e. all *admin* `User`s refer to the very same instance of class `Role`.

`User` mapping:

```
 <class name="User" lazy="false" table="Users">
  <id name="Id" type="int">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" column="Username" />
  <bag name="RoleList" table="User_Role" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="save-update">
    <key column="UserId" foreign-key="Id"/>
    <many-to-many class="Role" column="RoleId"/>
  </bag>
 </class>
```

`Role` mapping:

```
  <class name="Role" lazy="false" table="Roles">
    <id name="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="Rolename"/>
    <property name="Description"/>
  </class>
```

There are three DB tables: one for `User`s, one for `Role`s and the third is for the many-to-many relation (with two foreign keys: `UserId` and `RoleId`). A primary key is the composite key of those two.

The problematic *scenario*: the roles are predefined. In my C# code I am constructing a *user*, while attaching the *role* to it. The role is an object that was successfully fetched from DB with correct *id*. I am trying to save that *user* in the database.

Now to the **question**: I am receiving a *duplicate key* DB error, since NHibernate is trying to insert the `Role` object into the appropriate table. Since the `RoleId` already belongs to the existing *role*, I would expect that no new role will be inserted in DB.

*Gory details*: I've also tried to debug the NHibernate and seen that for some reason `EntityIdentityInsertAction` receives a `Role` and calls base constructor. In the call to the base constructor the `Id` parameter is a simple hard-coded *null*. The stack trace also contains a call to `SaveWithGeneratedId()` (somewhere earlier in the chain), which implies that the `Id` for the existing `Role` object is not counted for some reason.

This is all the info I've succeeded to find so far. Please tell what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first gut reaction is that you don't want cascade="save-update" on the Roles collection off the User.

You'd only want that, if you want changes you make to the actual Roles to be saved/updated when you save the User.

I assume what you were going after was making sure the relationship saves, but that happens regardless of your cascade setting.